# Can I use a chromebook as a Fileshare Server?

Tags: windows, networking

Afternoon everyone!

I am looking to set up an old chromebook as a fileshare server. This wouldn't be anything too crazy, I'd most likely just use it to store media and documents. Would I be able to set things up so that I could connect to it from a PC and get my files?

The set up would consist of a chromebook, connected to the router via wifi (can do Ethernet if needed), my PC/Macbook would be the devices connecting to it for moving files around and taking them out and such.

I was thinking SSH, as I know chrome supports that, but I don't know and haven't been able to find out if chromebooks themselves can be ssh'd into.
I have been looking around the internet for the past few days trying to find a solution to this, but haven't been able to find a definitive answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Connect to it over the internet? Or on a local network?

Comment: Would be over the same WiFi network. I could connect the chromebook to the router via Ethernet if needed, I would just need to buy an adapter.

Comment: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/access-network-share-files-chromebook/

Comment: @Moab That only works in the opposite direction.

Comment: @jpaugh I saw that article a few times, I was wondering if it would work both ways. Thank you for clarifying (even if it was unintentional).

Comment: That article relies on a network share existing already, and it would be a different process to set up a network share on a Chromebook (if that's even possible), instead of setting it up on a Windows computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way (with a high amount of work compared to the benefit) is to install a [Linux chroot environment](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook#0)  to the Chromebook, and then install Samba to that linux environment and setting up a network share that way. However, this would all be command-line only, and maybe not the most efficient way.

However, [this presentation](https://sambaxp.org/fileadmin/user_upload/sambaXP2018-Slides/Justen-Samba_and_ChromeOS_-_the_Start_of_a_Beautiful_Friendship.pdf) leads me to believe that Samba is already included in ChromeOS, which is why you can access fileshares in the first place. Maybe you could access and reconfigure the Samba instance that Google has already installed for you. [Here are some instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!) which would have to be modified, since they're for Ubuntu.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help. I have considered making said chromebook dual-boot before, I just never had a reason to. I will go ahead and move forward with this tonight!

Comment: 7AN70. Actually, dual boot is another option I didn't even mention. It's probably easier than chrooting, but also more risky, unless you have experience with it.

Comment: (Just make sure to take a backup beforehand.)

Comment: Doesn't matter too much to me, I'd rather just Chroot if I'm being honest. There's like 2 word docs on the HDD of the chromebook, so I wouldn't lose anything important if I did accidentally lose things. I really do appreciate your help in this subject. Thank you!